# Editar valores de applicationSettings en el .exe.config

Tags: asp.net, windows-forms, framework

tengo una aplicación tipo servicio de Windows y se guardaron algunas configuraciones por medio de applicationSettings y funcionan correctamente pero tengo inconveniente para modificarlos pues siempre me toma el valor con el que compile y no lo que tengo en el archivo .exe.config.

¿Cómo se debe actualizar el archivo .exe.config o como se debe obtener la información de este archivo de forma que  tome la información del .exe.config ?